# Value doesn't reset in a setInterval

Tags: jquery

I've an absolute div moving in the screen. When the div exit the screen I reset the value, this is the code:

```
    setInterval( function() {
        if( p2.offset().top <= 1 ) {
             p2.css('bottom','50').css('left','400');
        }
        p2.css('bottom', '+=1').css('left', '+=1');
    }, 10 );
```

When I put an alert in the if condition I see this alert, but the code *`p2.css('bottom','50').css('left','400')`* seems to be not executed... The div continue to move outside the screen without reset at `bottom: 50px` and `left: 400px`.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: How are you defining `p2`? can you post more code? How much is div height were `p2`is? what other CSS has `p2`?

Comment: Could you add the definition of p2 please ? And, it may not be any issue, but did you try with some units, e.g. '50px', '400px' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify your unit, and it'll work:

```
p2.css('bottom','50px').css('left','400px');
```

Or, pass an object to the `css()` method:

```
p2.css({bottom:50, left:400});
```

This assumes that you are talking pixels.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byZMf/)

Comment: very nice answer, especially the object part.

Comment: @Bigood just a little nitpicking, javascript does not have associative arrays;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the unit when you change the css :

```
p2.css('bottom','50px').css('left','400px');
```

### EDIT

Sorry, I didn't know that, but you can use `+=1` as you did.

<strike>Plus, you can't use operators like `+=` in a jQuery attribution of css.</strike>

You'd rather do :

```
var newBottom = (parseInt(p2.css('bottom')) + 1) + "px";
var newLeft = (parseInt(p2.css('left')) + 1) + "px";

p2.css('bottom', ).css('left', '+=1');
```

Comment: I agree on the unit point, but you can use `+=` operator (with jQuery >= 1.6)

Answer (score -2):

It does, it's just overwritten...

```
setInterval( function() {
        if( p2.offset().top <= 1 ) {
             p2.css('bottom','50').css('left','400');
        }else{
             p2.css('bottom', '+=1').css('left', '+=1');
        }
    }, 10 );
```

Comment: The increment by one does not affect (in terms of overriding) the setting to 50 when triggering the if condition. It just set to 50 and then immediately incremented.

Comment: if he did not use an else branch its maybe because he wants to execute that function always and not under condition